# Interface implementation not using the method parameter

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have one interface

```
public interface ItemFilter{
   public List<Item> filter (List<Item> items, List<Obj1> obj1List, List<Obj2> obj2List)
}
```

There are three implementation for this.

```
public Class Filter1 implements ItemFilter {
    public List<Item> filter (List<Item> items, List<Obj1> obj1List, List<Obj2> obj2List) { 
         // Some logic like 
         if (obj1List != null) { 
             return items;
         }
    }
} 

 public Class Filter2 implements ItemFilter {
    public List<Item> filter (List<Item> items, List<Obj1> obj1List, List<Obj2> obj2List) {              
         // Some logic like 
         if (obj2List != null) { 
             return items;
         }
} 

 public Class Filter3 implements ItemFilter {
    public List<Item> filter (List<Item> items, List<Obj1> obj1List, List<Obj2> obj2List) { 
         // Some logic like 
         if (obj1List.size() !=0 && obj2List.size() !=0 ) { 
             return items;
         }
    }
}
```

`Filter1` is using `obj1List` to filter the `items` and `Filter2` is using `obj2List` to filter the `items` and `Filter3` is using `obj1List` and `obj2List` to filter the `items`.

I want to have a `filterChain` which would iterate through all the filters in loop.

```
 public Class FilterChain implements ItemFilter {
        // Injected the Filter1, Filter2, Filter3 from guice multibinder
        @Inject
        private Set<ItemFilter> itemFilters;

    public List<Item> filter (List<Item> items, List<Obj1> obj1List, List<Obj2> obj2List) { 
         List<Item> resultItems = items; 
         for(ItemFilter itemFilter : itemFilters) {
             resultItems = itemFilter.filter(resultItems, obj1List, obj2List);
         }
        return resultItems;
    }
}
```

Here Class `Filter1` filter method implementaion would be having the extra `obj2List` as variable. Is it ok to have variable in interface declaration that is not used in one implementation?

Main idea is, Having different filters makes it easy to decouple the filtering logic in different classes. Different filters are using different parameters to filter the `List<Item>`.

Comment: `Public class Interface ` is a class not interface.

Comment: Is it `items == obj1List == obj2List`, hence just with another type declared? Or are those three distinctive `List`s?

Comment: "There are two implementation" - and you show us three?

Comment: Why does this have to be an interface. If you're dealing with 3 different types and 3 different filters, wouldn't it make more sense to instantiate those 3 filters separately. Also, java.util.stream.Stream.filter is probably what you truly need.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: per the suggestion above, this question would be off-topic on for CR in its current form because it appears to involve stub code. It may be appropriate for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Java 8 provides Lamba's which are anonymous functions, you can do that with lambdas

Comment: Unused parameters tend to be a code smell. It may be better to refactor as in @William Burnham's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely ok for some method implementations to ignore some of the method arguments.

Of course, in such a situation you should think about the role of all the arguments, and maybe your code can be refactored to use fewer arguments. But if you don't see a good refactoring doing that, stay with the partially-ignored arguments.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it ok to have variables in the interface not used in the implementation" is subjective. Java certainly won't prohibit you from doing it. If you can refactor though maybe it will be neater, with a parametrised solution for example.

```
public <T> void filter(List<T> items);
```

and then you have your implementations

```
public <T> void filter(List<T> items) {
    // do stuff 
}
```

in each implementation with different logic as required.